# Google Analytics API V4 Events Flow

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics API V4 and I want to reproduce the "Events Flow" like the screenshot.

Do you think it is possible to do so? And, if yes, can you help me? I dont know what I need for metrics, dimensions, etc.

Thanks in advance !

[Google Analytics API V4 Events Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG56a.png)

Comment: Data wise its probably possible, Graphic wise again its probably possible.   The data is there why not give it a try and come back with any code you are having issues with.   I would think that its the Events dimensions and metrics to start with.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Apparently, it's possible with the premium version.